# Removing unwanted comma for JSON formatting batch

Tags: json, batch-file, delayedvariableexpansion

I'm trying to print out the list of patches in JSON format as such:

```
"patches" : {
"1" : "KB123456",
"2" : "KB123456", ...
```

However this is what I'm getting:

```
"patches" : {
"1" : "",
"2" : "patch[2]",
"3" : "patch[3]", ...
```

This is my code

```
@echo off 
set count1=1    
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set patches="wmic qfe get HotfixID"
for /f "skip=1" %%i in (' %patches% ') do for /f "delims=" %%j in ("%%i") do (
    set patch[%count1%]=%%j
    set /a count1=count1+1
)

if %count1%==1 (
    echo "patch" : "%patch[1]%",
) else  (
    echo "patches" : {
    set index=0

    :loop
    set /a index=index+1
    for /f "tokens=1" %%G in (" %patch[1]% ") do set p1=%%G ::<---*
    echo %p1%
    rem set p=%patch[!index!]%
    rem echo "!index!" : "%p%",
    if NOT "%index%" == "%count1%" goto :loop

    set p=%patch[%count1%]%
    echo "%count1%" : "%p%"
    echo }
)
endlocal
```

In my first `for` loop I'm setting the array patch to each patch received from the command output. Afterwards, I'm trying to read each element in the array and print them in order.

* Here it does print the first element correctly. But when I replace that with

```
 for /f "tokens=1" %%G in (" %patch[!index!]% ") do set p1=%%G
```

it gives me an empty variable.

How do I pass on a variable inside another variable?

Comment: You're initializing %count1% to 1, but %index% to 0.  That's what's causing the empty first element.  Init %count1% to 0 and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I'm still getting the same thing. even if the %count1% = 0 shouldn't I see `"patch[0]"`?

Comment: I don't think so, because you're incrementing count1 prior to setting the first element.  The first element in your array is `patch[1]`.  But if `patch[1]` is empty, then you might have to change `skip=1` to `skip=2` in your `for /f` loop.

Comment: Oh right. I put the count under the set `patch[%count%]`. So it should start with `patch[1]` now as you said but it still shows `""`. I did try using `skip=2` but it didn't do anything. I edited my question. Maybe that will be an easier fix.

Comment: In your "Here it does print the first element...." `for /f` command, you've got the order of variable delays switched.  The inner needs instant expansion, and the outer, delayed.  Try `for %%G in (!index!) do set "p1=!patch[%%G]!"` to reverse them.  Or you could use `call call set "p1=%%%%patch[%%index%%]%%%%"` or similar, but that gets awkward and hard to read / maintain very quickly.

Comment: Alright I replaced that line by your suggestion `for %%G in (!index!) do set "p1=!patch[%%G]!"` and changed the line below to `echo !p1!`. What I get is the very last patch and then a bunch of `Echo is off.` Somehow it starts from the end. but when I printed the index. it was in ascending order...

Answer (score 0):

So I discovered that in batch the `for` loop doesn't act the same way as in other languages. It seems like instead of an iteration, it does everything at the same time. If you want to increment a variable and do something with it within a `for` loop you need to add `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and put the variable between `!`. However once you are outside the loop you can access it using `%`_`%` like I did with `count_patch`.

```
@echo off 
set count_patch=0
set idx=0
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set patches="wmic qfe get HotfixID"
for /f "skip=1" %%i in (' %patches% ') do for /f "delims=" %%j in ("%%i") do (
      set /a count_patch=count_patch+1
      set patch[!count_patch!]=%%j  
)

if %count_patch%==1 (
     echo "patch" : "%patch1%",
) else  (
echo "patches" : {

 for /f "skip=1" %%i in (' %patches% ') do for /f "delims=" %%j in ("%%i") do (
    set /a idx = idx+1
    if !idx!==%count_patch% ( echo "!idx!" : "%%j" ) else ( echo "!idx!" : "%%j",) 
)
echo }
)
endlocal
```

So what I did was, I counted the number of patches and then iterated through them again until my index (idx) had the same value as the patch count and printed that result without a comma.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather simple for [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html):

```
wmic qfe get HotfixID | xidel.exe -s - -e "{'patches':{|tokenize(normalize-space($raw),' ') ! {position():.}|}}"
```

Pipe the command to Xidel's input. Create the JSON-object "patches". From there process the input by first normalizing the trailing white-space and second creating a sequence of every entry. Next populate the object with the sequence index and its value.

Output:

```
{
  "patches": {
    "1": "KB123456",
    "2": "KB123456",
    "3": "KB123456",
    [...]
    "100": "KB123456",
  }
}
```